# PostgreSQL: сгруппировать записи, чтобы сумма внутри каждой группы не превышала заданное число

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице есть поля `id`, `price` и другие. Как выбрать записи, удовлетворяющие условию:

не важно сколько будет выбрано записей, главное чтобы сумма значений всех записей по полю `price` была не больше какого-то определенного числа.

Допустим, надо выбрать записи в сумме до 10. Пример таблицы:

```
-------------
 id  |  price
 1   |  2.00
 2   |  2.00
 3   |  2.00
 4   |  2.00
 5   |  2.00
 6   |  5.00
 7   |  4.00
 8   |  4.00
```

В результате должно вывести записи с id:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
либо
`6, 7`
либо
`4, 5, 6`
либо
`7, 8`
либо
`1, 2, 3, 7`

Вариантов может быть много, но все они должны быть меньше 10, если сложить в результате поля price всех записей.

На примере из жизни это выглядело бы так:

Мне нужно дать продавцу 10 рублей, а какими монетами не важно, лишь бы в результате было 10 рублей. В моей задаче может быть меньше или равно 10, допустим, если нет нужных монет, чтобы дать по рассчет.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что придется выбирать все и обрабатывать в коде. (дальше фантазия, так как конкретно с postgre не работал)Либо можно сделать хранимку, которая будет проходить курсором по таблице, забрасывать в массив id'шники и считать текущую сумму прайса.

Comment: Как то совершенно не ясно чего же вы хотите, приведите пример исходных данных и что должно быть на выходе. Вот есть скажем запись с ID=1 и price=1, она как сама по себе будет "до десесяти" так и в группе с разными другими записями в куче комбинаций так же окажется "до 10" и что в итоге на выходе, эта запись должна быть показана много раз в разных группах и раз подразумеваются некие группы записей их же надо как от отличать друг от друга, нумеровать например

Comment: это задача о рюкзаке. ее решения я никогда не смотрел, но вам, очевидно, нужны именно они.

Comment: [Задача о ранце](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5) Не уверен, что на sql это удобно решать, хотя можно попробовать "жадный алгоритм".

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать решить задачу через оконные функции

```
SELECT
  CEIL(total / 10) AS grp,
  ARRAY_AGG(price) AS prices,
  ARRAY_AGG(id) AS ids
FROM
  (SELECT
    id,
    price,
    SUM(price) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS total
  FROM
    tbl) AS tbl
GROUP BY
  grp;
```

Результат выполнения запроса

```
 grp |   prices    |     ids
-----+-------------+-------------
   1 | {2,2,2,2,2} | {1,2,3,4,5}
   2 | {5,4}       | {6,7}
   3 | {4}         | {8}
```